# Firebase - How to find the name of other children using a child?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

In firebase, I'm trying to make a login system where a user can login using his/her username and password. However, as firebase authentication requires email id and password, I have another database where both the username and email id are stored under a parent(I'm not sure if parent is the right word though) as its children. The name of the parent is randomly generated.

When a user logs in, I need to go to this database and find out the email address whose "brother" is the username entered. I tried keeping the username as the parent's name, but then for specific reasons, I had to change it back to this structure. So how do I accomplish this with the new structure(where both email and username are children)? Here is the function which I used when the username was the parent, to find the email id.

```
function getEmail(username) {
    var usersRef = database.ref(username).child("email");
    usersRef.on("value", function(snapshot) {
        email = snapshot.val();
    }, function (errorObject) {
        console.log("The read failed: " + errorObject.code);
    });
}
```

EDIT: Here is the JSON:

```
{
  "user 1" : {
    "email" : "test1@example.com",
    "username" : "Test1"
  },
  "user 2" : {
    "email" : "test2@example.com",
    "username" : "Test2"
  }
}
```

Comment: Instead of describing the data structure you're trying to query, edit your question to include a small snippet of the actual JSON (as text). You can get this by clicking the "Export JSON" link in your [Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data).

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Ok, I have now added the JSON to my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need a query to get the result you want:

```
var usersRef = database.ref().orderByChild("username").equalTo(username);
usersRef.once("child_added", function(snapshot) {
    email = snapshot.val().email;
}, function (errorObject) {
    console.log("The read failed: " + errorObject.code);
});
```

My code uses `once("child_added"` since you're probably only interested in the first matching child.

Alternatively, you can modify you data structure to use the user names as the key:

```
"emailsByUsernames": {
  "Test1" : "test1@example.com",
  "Test2" : "test2@example.com",
}
```

Then you can directly lookup the email like this:

```
var usersRef = database.ref(emailsByUsernames).child(username);
usersRef.on("value", function(snapshot) {
    email = snapshot.val();
}, function (errorObject) {
    console.log("The read failed: " + errorObject.code);
});
```

Comment: I didn't understand the second method, but the first one totally works! Thank you so much!